# WP7 location tools doesn't fire positionChanged event

Tags: windows-phone-7, gps, location

Trying to test my WP7 app that uses location following [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202933%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) tutorial.

I have additional tools open, start the emulator from VS, let the app launch and then I place a pin in Live-mode in the Additional Tools Location utility, but no event is fired. 
**Is there anything wrong with my code?**

```
public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitWatcher();
        }

private void InitWatcher()
    {
        geoWatcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
        geoWatcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(geoWatcher_PositionChanged);
        geoWatcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(geoWatcher_StatusChanged);
    }

    private void geoWatcher_PositionChanged(object sender, GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate> e)
    {
        var lol = e;
    }

    private void geoWatcher_StatusChanged(object sender, GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var FK = e;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that you have to start the GeoCoordinateWatcher:

```
geoWatcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
geoWatcher.PositionChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionChangedEventArgs<GeoCoordinate>>(geoWatcher_PositionChanged);
geoWatcher.StatusChanged += new EventHandler<GeoPositionStatusChangedEventArgs>(geoWatcher_StatusChanged);
geoWatcher.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to call the Start method on your GeoCoordinateWatcher instance?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee808853.aspx